# Julia : How to store tuples in different files?

Tags: file, julia

l want to store each tuple X[p] in a different file
X[1] in mini_batch1.jld  X[2] in mini_batch2.....
but my code below stores (duplicate) all the tuple of X[p] in the files created. Let's see an example :

```
m= 100
k= 3 # number of tuples or partition
y=rand_gen(m,k)

(3,[[-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0],[1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0],[1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0]])
```

l want to have in :
mini_batch1 the first tuple

```
[-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0]
```

mini_batch2 the second tuple

```
[1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0]
```

and so on. However my code do the job of creating the mini_batches files but fail to store one by one tuple. how can l fix that ?

```
workspace()
using JLD, HDF5

function gen_random(m,k)

    # m the length of the vector , for instance m=100000 and k
    # the number  of partitions let's set k=16
    s = rand(m)
    # Pkg.add("JLD"), Pkg.add("HDF5") these two packages are needed
    # in order to store our vectors in files under the extension jld
    # allow to convert each random number to -1 or 1

    X=float_to_binary(s)
    parts= kfoldperm(length(X),k)
    # l want to store each tuple X[p] in a different file
    # X[1] in mini_batch1.jld  X[2] in mini_batch2.....
    # but my code below store all the tuple X[p] in the files created.
    for p in 1:length(parts)
        file =jldopen(@sprintf("my path to file/mini_batch%d.jld", p),"w")
        write(file, "X", [X[p] for p in parts])
        close(file)
    end
    return [X[p] for p in parts]

    function float_to_binary(s,level=0.4)
        for i=1:length(s)
            s[i] = s[i] > level ? 1.0 : -1.0
        end
        file = jldopen("/my path/mydata.jld", "w")
        write(file, "s", s)  # alternatively, say "@write file A"
        close(file)
        return s
    end


    function kfoldperm(l,k)
        n,r = divrem(l,k)
        b = collect(1:n:l+1)
        for i in 1:length(b)
            b[i] += i > r ? r : i-1
        end
        p = randperm(l)
        return [p[r] for r in [b[i]:b[i+1]-1 for i=1:k]]
    end
```

Comment: Wouldn't `write(file, "X", X[p])` do the trick? (i.e., the likely problem is the comprehension).

Comment: no it's not working because it will read the first value of the first tuple. for example if p = 4 . X[1] will be the first value of the first tuple, X[2] will be the second value of the first tuple, X[3] the third value of the first tuple, X[4] the forth value of the first tuple. but l'm looking for this structrure  X[1] the whole first tuple, X[2] the whole second tuple and so on

Comment: y=gen_random(m,k) # m = 100 , k =4 for instance
(4,[[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0],[1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0],[1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0]])

Comment: here is the structure of a tuple l want to get in each file : file 1 => tuple 1  [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0]  and so on. hope that it helps you better to capture the problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Having all the data be 1 and -1 makes the example a little harder to read, so here's an example with more distinguishable numbers:

```
julia> using JLD

julia> X = Vector{Int}[[1,2], [3,4]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,2]
 [3,4]

julia> for i = 1:2
           jldopen("file$i.jld", "w") do file
               write(file, "X", X[i])
           end
       end

julia> X1 = load("file1.jld", "X")
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> X2 = load("file2.jld", "X")
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
```

Comment: it's not the same here l'm using a tuple  the first argument represents the number of tuples inside the tuple which is 4 then we have the forth tuples (4,[[2,3,5],[8,9,15],[17, 6, 45, 7],[78, 1 ,45, 2])

Comment: Then just use `write(file, "X", X[2][i])`

Comment: Or if you need that first element, `write(file, "X", (1, X[2][i]))`.